# Angular view / scope not updating even when apply is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have a global function thats called by a different library, that I'd like to impact my scope when its called.

In my controller I have:

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

   $scope.nextAvailable = false;

   $scope.thirdParty = window.thirdPartyFn = function() {
     $scope.nextAvailable = true;
     $scope.$apply();
   };

});
```

When I log nextAvailable in the console after, it does return true (within that function obviously, so I'm confident its being called properly) - but it does not seem to update the surrounding scope within the enclosing controller. Any ideas?

Comment: `nextAvailable` is updating. Elaborate on `update the surrounding scope within the enclosing controller`.

Comment: in my view I have something like, ng-show="nextAvailable", which never updates... I also have a fn (not shown) which tests nextAvailable, and it also sees it as false.

Comment: I'm testing it and it works fine. So it's something else, basic updating scope variable from global function works as it should.

Comment: When you test it - you call window.thirdPartyFn() - and it updates the scope?

Comment: first put nextAvailable inside an object. do not mess your global function with scope function. If your global function need to make a hack call to scope function, declare it separately, inside your global function find your scope `angular.element("#any_element_in_scope").scope()` you will need $scope.$apply in global function.

Comment: @Elliot http://plnkr.co/edit/tNH5h2imjHSJSjFv36QY?p=preview